# parsing non-standard datetime string to date object

Tags: python, pandas

I can't figure out how to parse this string to date time correctly, no matter what format I try it says time data does not match format.

```
# df['_01_FISCPER'] is like '2018011' i.e November 2018
df['FISCPER_DT'] = pd.to_datetime(df['_01_FISCPER'], format='%yyyy%mmm')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`format=` takes an `strftime` compatible format string](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html). `%yyyy%mmm` would match a 2-character year, the literal `yyy`, then a 2-character month and the literal `mm`.

For `2018011`, ie. `YYYY0MM`, you might want to try `format='%Y0%m'`.